# How to turn a json array into rows in postgres table

Tags: json, postgresql

json data

```
{
"metaData":[{"name":"TABLE_NAME"},{"name":"TABLESPACE_NAME"},{"name":"STATUS"}],
"rows":[["TEST_TR","ABC","VALID"],["T_BEFORE","DEF","VALID"]]
}
```

Some query:

```
select  json...
```

```
TABLE_NAME    |TABLESPACE_NAME | STATUS
--------------+----------------+-------
TEST_TR       |ABC             | VALID
T_BEFORE      |DEF             | VALID
```

Sorry for my poor question. 
I want to convert "json data" to table rows format using postgresql json functions.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems woefully incomplete. It's not clear what your problem actually is? What server / environment / programming language are you using to process this JSON data? If you are using a Java, do you wish to use an ORM based solution (e.g. Hibernate, JPA, etc...).

Lacking this information, let's assume that you intend to construct SQL insert statements for these objects. My advice to you is to formulate by hand a batch SQL insert statement which corresponds to the data you've given. Once you have done that, it should be a straightforward process to write some code which will build these statements on the fly.

Finally, be sure to utilized 'prepared' statements in order to help guard against SQL injection attacks.